# while opens the Oracle database facing some error

Tags: oracle11g

Hi i am trying to install oracle, i installed completed but while is open the database control- orcl , error is coming in browser that " Your connection is not private".[image]

Comment: as i can see that you have used https:// for ssl but your ssl is not CA signed so your browser is showing SSL warning, simply you should click on Advance option and click proceed any way.

Comment: Thank you .ya i followed which you told .. now the page will be blank. This is the url " https://localhost:1158/em/console/logon/logon " this page is blank now

Comment: I want to learn the vb and oracle, i installed vb and doing simple code without using oracle. But now i installed oracle while opening this error is comming. so plz help me, how to recover this and proceed.

Comment: may i know your oracle version that you have installed

Comment: i haved installed Oracle11g

Comment: R u  there?? How can we go next line in SQLplus command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All Oracle doesn't provide web interface so don't try to open on browser. and if don't know how to create DataBase than you should watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoMiy5vlhU4

I know web interface for MySQL and MSSQL but i don't know any web interface for Oracle 11g.

Comment: ok sure i will watch that video and let u know my doubt latter.. thank you

Comment: Ya Database configuration assistance i hav configured fully, then how i want to open the database now?

Comment: I opend my sql plus command and gave sql> startup but it throws ORA-01031:insufficient privillage then what i hav to do sir?